# Why does Illustrator CS6 read font information from a SVG file incorrectly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, svg, font-size

I have a bunch of SVG files that were created by [MagicDraw](http://www.nomagic.com). In these files, I have several font definitions, e.g.,

```
<text x="152" space="preserve" font-size="11" y="376.958"
   clip-path="url(#clipPath2)" stroke="none">
   MyClassName</text>
```

So it is clearly defined that the font size should be 11px. However, when I open the file in Illustrator CS6, the font size is now `8,25`. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding the units in? i.e.: font-size="11pt"
or compared with a file that works to see what might be different?

Comment: Another place to look - are there any elements or groups the text is in that have a transform? Could be, it's reading the size as 11, then scaling it by 75% because of something elsewhere

Comment: @Emilie I opened the file with the text editor and added the units, but same result.

Comment: have you tried selecting the right unit of measure when you are creating the new file in illustrator? maybe that's why it's not working, since from what I read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#FontSizeProperty the font-size seems to inherit the unit of the file it's pasted (if I understood correctly)

Comment: strauberry: How about adding a link to an example SVG that has this problem? Or, making the simplest possible SVG that has this problem, then posting the code in your question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MagicDraw, but this answer - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/158290/132379 - converts text to outlines (Adobe Illustrator, so may not apply).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

11px equates to roughly 8.25pt - I reckon you've got your Illustrator Units set to pt but expecting it to read the px value.

To change the units Illustrator uses for type go the `Edit Menu > Preferences > Units` and changed the `Type` dropdown to `Pixels`.

Comment: Or just change the number in the svg file.

Comment: That's definitely an option, although it probably makes more sense to work with a single unit of measure where possible, it saves having to do annoying conversions!